# Транспонирование матрицы (numpy массива) в python

Tags: python, numpy

я имею:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6])
```

и теперь каким образом я могу транспонировать эту матрицу, чтобы получить

```
a = [[0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6]]
```

?

Comment: Как оказалась с транспонирование такого вида матрицы проблем нет, a.transpose() выдает результат. C транспонированием одномерного вектора возникоют проблемы, т.е. такого вида a = np.array([[0, 1, 2]])

Comment: а какие проблемы с одномерным вектором? Попробовал, получается `array([[1], [2], [3]])`.

Comment: результат получается все тот же 1х3, а не как мне хотелось бы 3х1,

Comment: [[1], [2], [3]] - это и есть 3x1 (три строки по одному элементу).

Comment: Кстати, раз уж сами нашли ответ по поводу транспонирования, добавьте его.

Comment: прошу прощения ошибся

Comment: Для одномерного массива, можно добавить новую колонку перед траспонированием: [`a[:,None].T`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11885503/4279). `np.array([[0, 1, 2]]).shape = (1, 3)` поэтому он уже 2-D и `a.T` и так работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Транспонирование массива в numpy выполняется так:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6]])
a = a.transpose()
print(a)
```

Результат:

```
[[0 4]
 [1 5]
 [2 6]]
```

Comment: `a.T` транспонированный вид возвращает.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6])
a = a.T
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
def transpouse(mat):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(len(mat[0])):# mat - изначальная матрица
        matrix.append(list())
        for j in range(len(mat)):
            matrix[i].append(mat[j][i])
    return matrix
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В вопросе используется матрица в виде массива numpy. У массивов numpy уже есть методы транспонирования, в контексте данного вопроса использование ручного транспонирования через списки неоправданно.