# Ошибка в коде pytorch : mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x100 and 1x15)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

Код брал из репозитория [тут](https://github.com/SlinkoIgor/Neural_Networks_and_CV/blob/master/module03_sin_prediction.ipynb)

вылезет ошибка в forward функции на линии x=self.fc1(x)

Ошибка звучит так `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x100 and 1x15)` 
Подскажите что с этим сделать? Как устранить ошибку?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно почитать "Умножение матриц"
Матрицы A и B могут быть перемножены, если они совместимы в том смысле, что число столбцов матрицы A равно числу строк B

В вашем случае поможет [транспонирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500957/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-numpy-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-python) одной из матриц... если это допустимо.

Comment: Благодарю! Я так то понимал что что то с размерностью не так. Но я не совсем понимаю что именно эти матрицы mat1 и mat2 из себя представляют ? Это x_validation и y_validation ? или что то другое? Но смущает другое! По идее этот код должен работать из коробки. Почему то у меня не работает. unsqueeze_(1) я применил к обоим матрицам, а вот что я ещё могу сделать?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если в сообщение mat1 и mat2 будут одной размерности, то всё должно заработать? Дело в том что я получаю даже такое сообщение: `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x100 and 1x100)`

Comment: нужно (1x100 and 100х1) или (100x1 and 1x100)

Comment: я пытаюсь поменять матрицу принудительно (что я считаю не правильно) но ничего не выходит. Дебагер вращает матрицу в комментарии как ему удобно теперь выдаёт так: `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (100x1 and 100x1)` хотя я менял только одну матрицу(как я думаю, я не знаю за правильные ли верёвочки дёргаю) Я комментирую unsqueeze_(1) для x матрицы. И меняю последовательность написания в `self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden_neurons,100)`
А так же ввожу один скрытый нейрон для сети, что в корне конечно не верно!

Comment: проверил на [https://colab.research.google.com/] - работает из коробки.

Comment: Проверьте, все ли секции кода у вас перенесены из исходника и все ли были запущены последовательно... На колабе все работает

Comment: Да, на колабе у меня тоже всё заработало, и код скопированный с колаба заработал. Пойду разбираться в чём была причина...

Answer (score 1):

Пропустил строки:

```
x_train.unsqueeze_(1)
y_train.unsqueeze_(1);
```